# How to send alerts generated from core banking system in multiple languages?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, banking, core-banking

I have to implement a solution which will translate the sms alerts generated from a core banking system into languages like "Hindi" and various Indian native languages.

What should be the approach provided I already have all types of alerts which are being sent currently in English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. So you need on-the-fly translation?

Comment: If you retrieve the message text via .properties files just create the corresponding entries in the appropriate .properties file (note that the language iso code would have to be part of the file name).

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? What you are describing here is fairly basic. A number of frameworks have support for this type of thing. Spring localized message-bundles together with som basic String.format() logic should get you pretty far. You can also use for advance templating like freemarker or somesuch. You'll have to get the english texts translated beforehand, of course.

Comment: @Gaurav, is the information regarding the preferred language is already with you (may be as a part of user registration) ?

Comment: @home: I have to basically get the thing done, I think the "Hindi" language translators are not that efficient so I have to think of some alternate logic for this task, like parsing the "English" alert strings and selecting their "Hindi" translation from some file, database like .resx file in .net.

Comment: @Santosh: Yes I already have that. I want to know how can I send the alert in Hindi while that alert is sent directly from Core Banking System to the user. Even if I redirect that alert to my code first, I have to change it into Hindi. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: @gaurav: How do you want to intercept an SMS message sent from the banking system directly to the user? It looks to me that the only solution is to modify the banking system so that it understands Hindi...

Comment: @home: You are right, it seems I have to propose some changes in the CBS too, but still the major part is if I can get that message in my written function, what logic should I implement in my function :D

Comment: You should get the insights of the CBS :-) In general multi-language support is implemented using some mapping approach (files, DB tables), for Java see @Santoshs answer.

Comment: Ideally the CBS should give you status codes and which u should be able to translate to actual message.

Comment: @Santosh: I will check that with CBS guys and then update if it is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resource files and move the alert texts to them. Even if it's dynamically generated texts you should be able to extract the correct text using either conditional logic or a chain of responsibility type architecture.

Here is a good intro to resource files in .NET: [resx on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following approach

1. Create different properties files for different language
2. Store the various messages against the keys for alert types
3. Use `java.util.Properties` instance to load all of these different files and store all of them in a map with the language as a key (This is all at start up).
4. At the time of sending message, I assume that you already have a user's language preference (received say while user registration ).
5. Now retrieve the java.util.Properties object from the map using the language key and the from that retrieve the message  from the message key.

   I am aware of the standard resource bundle type approaches for full fledged web application. Since a SMS driven application will not have access to the the locale of the user, I could think of this approach.
   Please share any other specially standard approach if any.

EDIT : Seems I miss-read the question. What Gaurav want is to use language translation on the fly.
But what I think is the banking system which being dealt with should not send messages in plain English but some type of status codes which can later be used to send messages in appropriate languages.